# Where can I find the private keystore file generated by the Android Studio "Generate Signed APK Wizard"?

Tags: android, apk, keystore, android-studio, android-keystore

I have used Android Studio's "Build" -> "Generate Signed APK..." -> "Generate Signed APK Wizard" to create a new keystore and sign an app that I want to publish to the Play Store. The problem I am having is I can't seem to locate the .keystore file I created... I need to be able to share the keystore with the other developers on my team. I have tried running find and locate commands in the terminal but the only thing that turns up is the debug.keystore... Does Android Studio hide the keystore file some place special? I set the Key Store Path to be "~/" on my mac, but again, when I go there, there are not .keystore files. How can I find it!?

Comment: FIXED! Figured out that Android Studio stores generated keystores in the /Applications/Android Studio.app/bin/ directory.

Comment: NOTE: Android Studio does not post fix the keystore file with ".keystore" so finding it may be a hard sometimes.

Comment: The default extension used by Android Studio v0.3.2 seems to be .jks

Comment: I could not find Android Studio.app folder in the Applications folder.